# The Kibana data has been lost while down the docker-compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm using elk docker image and using the below docker-compose file to kick start the ELK containers and storing the data in volume.

```
  version: '3.5'

   services:

   elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
     environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
     networks:
      - elk

   logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro
      - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

   kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
    volumes:
      - ./kibana/config/:/usr/share/kibana/config:ro
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

 networks:

  elk:
    driver: bridge
```

Kibana version 6.6.0

I used below command to start:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Observed that all three containers are up and running and I can able to publish my data into kibana and It can be visualized.

I just had situation to down this compose file and start up . But When I do that activity all the earlier kibana data has been lost.

```
docker-compose down
```

Is there any way that I can permanently store those records in machine (Some where in linux box) as backup else any database?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move elasticsearch data dir (`/usr/share/elasticsearch/data`) into a persistent docker volume like this:

```
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
      - ./es_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
     environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
     networks:
      - elk
```

Comment: Will it keep the data forever? won't be data lost even if I down the docker?

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan when you use `volume` statement in your docker-compose the local folder (`./es_data` in the example) will be mounted into your docker container. All the data being wrote will persist on the host, not in docker. So it won't be lost after docker restart (and even after you host machine restart). Check this https://docs.docker.com/storage/ for more information